# Add a row using certain column condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column value with value a and b ,add a row of value only for b and create a new column

```
value    val1    val2  val3

a         1       2     0

b         3       4     5

a         3       0     0

b         3       4     0
```

I expect a output

```
value  val1  val2  val3  total_a  total_b

a        1     2     0     3        
b       3     4     5               12

a       3     0     0     3                  
b       3     4     0               7
```

the code i tried

```
df['total_b']=df['value'].str.contains('b').apply(np.sum,axis=1)
```

but throwing a error there is no dimension of 0.

please try to solve this question

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please provide your full code which will help to fix the issue quickly.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
df['total_a'] = df.query('value == "a"').sum(1, numeric_only=True)
df['total_b'] = df.query('value == "b"').sum(1, numeric_only=True)
```

Output:

```
  value  val1  val2  val3  total_a  total_b
0     a     1     2     0      3.0      NaN
1     b     3     4     5      NaN     12.0
2     a     3     0     0      3.0      NaN
3     b     3     4     0      NaN      7.0
```

Or make it general with a loop while assigning the columns:

```py
for val in ["a", "b"]:
    df[f"total_{val}"] = df.query(f'value == "{val}"').sum(1, numeric_only=True)
```

Comment: Had roughly the same answer, so added it here if you don;t mind. Feel free to remove @scott

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'value':['a', 'b', 'a', 'b'], 'val1':[1, 3, 3, 3], 'val2':[2, 4, 0, 4], 'val3':[0,5,0,0]})

df['total_a']=df.loc[df['value']=='a',['val1' , 'val2', 'val3']].sum(axis = 1)
df['total_b']=df.loc[df['value']=='b',['val1' , 'val2', 'val3']].sum(axis = 1)

df.fillna('') # not recommended, put it only to match your desired output
```

Output:

```
  value  val1  val2  val3 total_a total_b
0     a     1     2     0     3.0        
1     b     3     4     5            12.0
2     a     3     0     0     3.0        
3     b     3     4     0             7.0
```